# How to increase the limit on the amount of HTMLImageElement.decode call?

Tags: javascript, image, decode

I'm trying to use [HTMLImageElement.decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode#Syntax) to improve the perf of my webapp. I realized This method can only be used 30 times, then any further call will be rejected with `EncodingError: The source image cannot be decoded.` while WebApp has hundreds of images. How do I do to decode all images ?

Comment: In the official site - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode#Syntax nothing has been mentioned about max number of times this method can be used. It seems like error has occurred while decoding the image, might be the image is too large or the image url is not valid.

Comment: If I start from 0, error messages will appear from 30. If I start from 10, error messages will appear around 40. You can try it with unique 100 images.